# How do I automatically bind my incoming JSON to a POJO? (Play 2.3.7 -- Java)

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0, jackson

This is how my controller method looks now:

```
public static Result createGoal() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return ok(toJson(Goal.create(mapper.convertValue(json, Goal.class))));
  }
```

This is how I would like it to look:

```
public static Result createGoal(Goal goal) {
    return ok(toJson(Goal.create(goal)));
}
```

I'm guessing my routes file would change from this:

```
POST       /goals               controllers.Goals.createGoal()
```

To this:

```
POST       /goals               controllers.Goals.createGoal(goal: Goal)
```

But that doesn't seem to work as I get a "Compilation error[not found: type Goal]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes, you need to prefix `Goal` class with full package name. More of it, Play! needs to know how to bind query or path parameters to `Goal` class, thus consider implementing `play.mvc.PathBindable` or `play.mvc.QueryStringBindable` interface.

`ObjectMapper` is an expensive class, thus consider binding your parameters using form:

```
Form.form(Goal.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Comment: That's unfortunate, it was implicit in Play 1.x as well as Dropwizard.